# Pagination and filter in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post, filter, pagination

I have a form, in which user can filter pending transactions. I want to use the pagination feature of Spring. This works (as I wanted) only if I don't want to filter (same as getAll() query).
My problem is if I post the form to the controller, it searches the filtered transactions, gives the information about the number of pages, total ect.. But if I click on the pagination button, it goes to the method which signature is GET (URL is for example localhost.../pending?page=2&size=20), and my form is initialized with default values. So the filter doesn't work, just the pagination.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pending", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
public String getPendingTransactions(@ModelAttribute("pendingForm") PendingTransactionForm pendingForm, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Pageable pageable) {
    PageWrapper<Transaction> transactionItems = new PageWrapper<Transaction>(transactionService.searchPendingItemsByParams(pendingForm, pageable));
    uiModel.addAttribute("pendingForm", pendingForm);
    uiModel.addAttribute("transactionItems", transactionItems);
    uiModel.addAttribute("shoplist", transactionService.getShopListForNotFinishedItems());
    return "transaction/pendingtransactions";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/pending", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processPendingTransactions(@ModelAttribute("pendingForm") PendingTransactionForm pendingForm, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Pageable pageable) {
    PageWrapper<Transaction> transactionItems = new PageWrapper<Transaction>(transactionService.searchPendingItemsByParams(pendingForm, pageable));
    uiModel.addAttribute("pendingForm", pendingForm);
    uiModel.addAttribute("transactionItems", transactionItems);
    uiModel.addAttribute("shoplist", transactionService.getShopListForNotFinishedItems());
    return "transaction/pendingtransactions";
}
```

Is there any solution, how to implement the filter and pagination together?

UPDATE: thanks to Jose Luis Martin's answer, it works!

```
@RequestMapping("/transactions")
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("pendingForm")
public class TransactionsController {

  @ModelAttribute("pendingForm")
  public PendingTransactionForm initializePendingForm() {
        return new PendingTransactionForm();
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/pending", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "text/html")
  public String getPendingTransactions(@ModelAttribute("pendingForm") PendingTransactionForm pendingForm, Model uiModel, Pageable pageable) {
       PageWrapper<Transaction> transactionItems = new PageWrapper<Transaction>(transactionService.searchPendingItemsByParams(pendingForm, pageable));
       uiModel.addAttribute("transactionItems", transactionItems);
       uiModel.addAttribute("shoplist", transactionService.getShopListForNotFinishedItems());
       return "transaction/pendingtransactions";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the filter in session using `@SessionAttributes`, so it will be available for pagination requests.

I wrote a example for displaytag and JDAL some time ago, but the controller is a Spring controller, so it could be useful for you.

see http://www.jdal.org/doc/displaytag.php